# Baixar dados de uma <table> paginada

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu tenho esse script que faz o download dos dados de uma tabela inteira no formato .xls, acontece que eu faço uma listagem inteira numa página só e não fica usual pois tem listagem que passa de 2000 linhas. Fiz uma tabela paginada que mostra 10 resultados por vez e queria que independente da paginação atual ao clicar no botão baixar ele realize o download da listagem completa, pois ele só faz da paginação atual.

Obs: não encontrei nada que trate algo semelhante, só listagem inteira na paginação atual.

Desde já agradeço!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function salvaPlanilha() {
var htmlPlanilha = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>PlanilhaConciliador</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>' + document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML + '</table></body></html>';

var htmlBase64 = btoa(htmlPlanilha);
var link = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64," + htmlBase64;

var hyperlink = document.createElement("a");
hyperlink.download = "ArquivoConciliador";
hyperlink.href = link;
hyperlink.style.display = 'none';

document.body.appendChild(hyperlink);
hyperlink.click();
document.body.removeChild(hyperlink); } </script>
```

Comment: Novaes, você poderia dar mais detalhes de como funciona essa paginação? Você exibe a planilha que tem dados de uma fonte, para exportar tudo, você tem que ter a tabela completa inevitavelmente, sendo assim, poderia pensar em contactar a fonte de dados e solicitar a planilha completa para salvar no arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado, tentarei isso aí